# Something curious is happening subtracting dates in a query - 70 days appears from nowhere :-/

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

UPDATE: Although I'm storing dates in dbase as DATE type, I knew I didn't need to CAST them as DATE. However, I now know - thanks to the linked suggestion - that a simple mathematical subtraction isn't the best solution and that DATEDIFF was the way forward. But I would not have found that out as easily or as quickly (Thanks again!!) if I hadn't posted the question in the first place :-)

[My original post]

I've recently resurrected an old PC, gone thru all the pains of installing Win7 updates, WAMPServer 3.2.6, etc... The PC is purposely Not connected to the net!

Setup is; WampServer, Apache v2.4.51, PHP v7.4.26, MySQL v5.7.36, and phpMyAdmin v5.1.1.

The table I'm querying contains, amongst other things, Arrival and Departure dates. Type DATE, NULL default value (Usual YYYY-MM-DD format), no index ... nothing special.

In the SELECT query, I'm subtracting arrival date from departure date to get number of days, then performing DATE_FORMAT on both (just for display purposes).

All is tickety-boo for the first 5 records, but the 6th and last mysteriously has 70 days added on to the result. But this only happens when Arrive in (say) November, Depart in December, or Arrive October, depart Nov. Ive NOT tried this with the rest of the year :-/

Anyone got any clues or ideas???

[image: Screen shot of query and results table]

Query giving odd results when subtracting two dates

Comment: [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) would probably work better

Comment: Meet Marakana's answer in the linked duplicate explains why you're seeing the weird math